# Prolog changing variables

Tags: prolog, translation, predicate

I am new to prolog, and am working on a problem where I have to take inputs to a predicate as english words (numbers), and then make a grid out of them. I have the grid down, but what I'm stuck on is how to get the english words into numbers... Here is what should happen:

```
grid(two,ten).   =>  (Perfectly fine and prints grid)
grid(one,one).   =>  (Perfectly fine and prints grid)
grid(3,four).    =>
    Use English, please!
    true
```

Here's my (updated!) code so far:

(At top)

```
number(one, 1).
number(two, 2).
number(three, 3).
```

... And then:

```
grid(Rows, Cols) :-
    number(Rows, R),
    number(Cols, C),
    help(R, C).
grid(_,_).
```

UPDATE: With the code above, I am getting true for everything, with no output. Are the calls to number stopping it?

Comment: Just make them facts in prolog. For example, `number(one,1).` and `number(two,2).` etc. You can use the word `translation` instead of `number` if you wish. It's totally up to you what you want to call it as long as it doesn't conflict with a built-in name in Prolog. Then you just say, `number(English, Number).` or whatever to get the number corresponding with the English into the variables `Number` and `English`.

Comment: Okay so moving forwards, I have facts like number(one, 1), number(two, 2), etc up top. And then in my predicate I'm saying:
grid(Rows, Cols) :-
number(Rows, R),
number(Cols, C),
help(R, C).
grid(_,_).

Would this help it at all? Because now I'm only getting true from every set of values I enter...

Comment: You're going to need to edit your problem and show your updated code.

Comment: Edited to look at! :)

Comment: If that's all you have and `help(R,C)` isn't defined, then the query to `help` will fail, Prolog will backtrack to `grid(_,_).` and that will simply yield success ("true"). Which is exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: Oh wow it works now! I had been missing a comma somewhere else. Thank you so much for all your help! All I need to do now is figure out how to print "Use English Please" if they enter an integer number. It would only happen if one of the number cases failed... How would I get that to say so?

Comment: Look up the `write` predicate.